# how do you make it so that www.site.com/123 or www.site.com/123/some-headline will both lead users to the same place which is www.site.com/123?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, routes

how do you make it so that  www.site.com/123 or www.site.com/123/some-headline www.site.com/123/anything-at-all will lead users to the same place which is www.site.com/123 ?   I think the routing in Ruby on Rails can do it.  But other than that, what other methods can do that.  can it be done by Apache alone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with rails routing or with mod_rewrite in Apache.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 2):

Using Mod Rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine ON 
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/*$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Using routes.rb

```
map.connect ':my_id/:headline', :controller => 'controller_name', 
            :action => 'action_name', :my_id => /[0-9]+/
```

Answer (score 1):

A combination of Apache's mod_rewrite and some regex should be all you need.

[mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Answer (score 0):

Although it does not answer exactly your question, most rails sites use a slug after a dash rather than a slash, just like this: www.site.com/123-my-headline.

You do this by making your own to_params method in the model.

No more work needs to be done because the find method will return the page #123 automatically since the ruby to_i method will return the integer that starts the string and ignore all characters starting with the first non-numerical character.

Answer (score 0):

As of rails 1.2.6 you can add both routes:

```
map.connect ':id', :controller=>:post,:action=>:show
map.connect ':id/:title', :controller=>:post,:action=>:show
```

The RESTful thing may vary

Hope it helps you